# Qt WebEngine : Is there a way to emulate a mobile browser?

Tags: qt, mobile, qtwebengine

The main question is in the title. I need to emulate a mobile browser in a desktop software. I need to switch from desktop view to mobile view and vice versa. My first idea was to resize the view to a mobile standard size. It works for major web site which only pays attention to the frame size.

But I'm not sure the webview is seen as a real mobile webview. Is there a way to configure Qt WebEngine as a mobile browser or simply fake it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the set the header `UserAgent` in Qt WebEngine.

https://varvy.com/mobile/vary-user-agent.html

As @demonplus noted, use the [httpUserAgent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineprofile.html#httpUserAgent-prop) property.

Comment: For changing user agent you need to use [httpUserAgent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineprofile.html#httpUserAgent-prop) property

Comment: Thank you ! This is just what I needed. I was looking for this property in the webview object.